How can i access to comments from ad with Marketing Api?
I am developing an application in which I need to obtain the comments of the ads that I generate from a campaign.
Through the marketing API, I can obtain the campaign ID, then the ad set ID, and finally the ad ID. However, when I try to obtain "/comments", I get the error "Tried accessing nonexisting field (comments) on node type (Ad)". Am i missing some permission ?
Through the marketing API, I can obtain the campaign ID, then the ad set ID, and finally the ad ID. However, when I try to obtain "/comments", I get the error "Tried accessing nonexisting field (comments) on node type (Ad)". Am i missing some permission ?
